# If $\forall x \in R, x^2-x \in Z(G)$, than $R$ is commutative

Tags: ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring such that for every $x\in R$ we have $x^2-x \in Z(G)$. Show that $R$ is a commutative ring.

---

*My thoughts*

What should I do? I could show that every $y \in R$ could be written in the shape $x^2-x$ but I don't know if that is true. We know that 
$y \cdot(x^2-x) \ = \ (x^2-x)\cdot y$ for any $x,y \in R$, but that doesn't mean that $xy = yx$. Please give me a hint

Comment: It's not necessarily the case that every $y$ can be written in the form $x^2-x$, take $\mathbb{Z}/2$ for example. It's tricky.

Comment: What is $G$? Z(G)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One possible hint: Working on $$(x+y)^2-(x+y).$$ to show that $xy+yx\in Z(R)$ could pave our way to solution. Indeed, when $xy+yx\in Z(R)$ then $$(xy+yx)y=y(xy+yx)\to xy^2=y^2x.$$ Now since $y^2-y\in Z(R)$ so $$y^2x-yx=xy^2-xy$$

Comment: Do you mean $(x+y)^2-(x+y)$?

Comment: @MorganO: Thanks for noting me that.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $R$ has $1$.

Then, for any $x \in R$,

$(1+x)^2-(1+x) \in Z(R)$, which shows: $(1+x^2+2x)-(1+x) \in Z(R)$, which implies that $x^2+x$ is in $Z(R)$ for all $x \in R$. So, $(x^2+x)-(x^2-x) \in Z(R)$ which implies $2x \in R$ for all $x \in R$. This easily implies $R$ is commutative.

Comment: Now I found that $(x^2-x) +(y^2-y) +2(xy-yx) \in Z(R)$. I can get rid of $x^2-x$ and $y^2-y$ by substraction, but I don't know what I should do when $1+1=0$ in $R$.

Comment: "This easily implies $R$ is commutative." Not true at all; consider matrices over a field of characteristic $2$.

Comment: I will get back at this.. I shall leave it up for now, though.

Comment: Presumably, $2x\in Z(R)$, not $2x\in R$. Also, $2x\in Z(R)$ would be true if $R$ has characteristic $2$. It's not obvious to me why this would imply $R$ is commutative.