# Proving Commutative ring with Conditions

Tags: ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring such that ${x^2}-x$ $\in$ $C(R)$ $\forall$ $x$ $\in$ $R$. Prove that $R$ is commutative.
 I have tried like this : 
Let $x$, $y$ $\in$ $R$. So , ${x^2}-x$ , ${y^2}-y$ $\in$ $C(R)$. Now, we have to prove that $xy$ $=$ $yx$.
Now, $y({x^2}-x)$ $=$ $({x^2}-x)y$ , 
$x({y^2}-y)$ $=$ $({y^2}-y)x$.
From these , I got that $x(x-y)y$ $=$ $y(x-y)x$ . Now I am stucked. Please help.

Comment: What is $C(R)$?

Comment: @tattwamasiamrutam it is probably the center of $R$. This question appears elsewhere on the site but not with answers apparently.

Comment: @rschwieb Have a look.

Comment: Also a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/906866/if-forall-x-in-r-x2-x-in-zg-than-r-is-commutative/906871

Answer (score 1):

Now $(x+y)^2-(x+y)=x^2+xy+yx+y^2-x-y \in C(R)$

Thus $xy+yx=x^2+xy+yx+y^2-x-y-(x^2-x)-(y^2-y) \in C(R)$ for all $x,y \in R$

In particular $(xy+yx)x=x(xy+yx) \implies xyx+yx^2=x^2y+xyx \implies yx^2=x^2y$

Also $y(x^2-x)=(x^2-x)y \implies yx^2-yx=x^2y-xy$

Thus we have $xy=yx$ for all $x,y \in R$.